# How to prove that a ring $R$ is Morita-equivalent to $M_n(R)$?

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules, representation-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $M_n(R)$ the ring of $n \times n$ matrices with elements in $R$. Let $\textrm{mod} R$ denote the category of left modules over $R$.

How to define a equivalent functor $F: \textrm{mod} R \to \textrm{mod} M_n(R)$?

In [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morita_equivalence#Examples), one defines $F(X) = X^n \in \textrm{mod} M_n(R)$ for a left $R$-module $X$.

I do not know how to define the inverse functor $F^{-1}$. In case that $n=2$, $(M_1, M_2)^{T} \in \textrm{mod} M_2(R)$, then what is $F^{-1}((M_1, M_2)^{T})$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me explain the general picture. Let $R,S$ be two rings. The cocontinuous functors $$\mathsf{Mod}(S) \longrightarrow \mathsf{Mod}(R)$$ are given by $P \otimes_R -$ for some $(R,S)$-bimodule $P$ - this the *Eilenberg-Watts Theorem*. It follows that pairs of pseudoinverse functors
$$\mathsf{Mod}(R) \longleftrightarrow \mathsf{Mod}(S)$$
are given by pairs $(P,Q)$, where $P$ is a $(R,S)$-bimodule and $Q$ is a $(S,R)$-bimodule such that $P \otimes_S Q \cong R$ as $(R,R)$-bimodules and $Q \otimes_R P \cong S$ as $(S,S)$-bimodules. These pairs (together with the isomorphisms actually) are called *Morita contexts*, since they classify Morita equivalences between $R$ and $S$. If you want to know more details, you can find them for instance in Lam's book *Lectures on modules and rings* in the chapter on Morita theory. There you can also find some details for the example below.

In the standard example $S=M_n(R)$, a possible choice is the $(R,M_n(R))$-bimodule $R^{1 \times n}=R^n$ (row vectors) and likewise the $(M_n(R),R)$-bimodule $R^{n \times 1}=R^n$ (column vectors). One has to check that $R^{n \times 1} \otimes_R R^{1 \times n} \cong M_n(R)$ as $(M_n(R),M_n(R))$-bimodules and $R^{1 \times n} \otimes_{M_n(R)} R^{n \times 1} \cong R$ as $(R,R)$-bimodules.

The corresponding pseudoinverse functors are
$$\mathsf{Mod}(R) \to \mathsf{Mod}(M_n(R)),~X \mapsto R^{n \times 1} \otimes_R X = X^{n \times 1}$$
and
$$\mathsf{Mod}(M_n(R)) \to \mathsf{Mod}(R),~ X \mapsto R^{1 \times n} \otimes_{M_n(R)} X \cong E_{11} X.$$

Comment: Thank you. But I have a problem: what is $E_{11}$? Whether $E_{11}$ is the matrix whose $(1,1)$-th entry is 1 and 0 elsewhere.

Comment: Yes. $E_{ij}$ are the standard matrix units.

Answer (score 6):

Given any $M_n(R)$-module $Y$, we can treat it like an $R$-module (since $R\hookrightarrow M_n(R)$ diagonally), in which case $Y=\bigoplus_i e_{ii}Y$ as $R$-modules. To see why $Y=\sum_i e_{ii}Y$, simply note $I_n=\sum_i e_{ii}$ and to see the sum is direct, suppose $y$ is in both $e_{ii}Y$ and $\bigoplus_{j\ne i}e_{jj}y$, then apply $e_{ii}$ to $y$ to get $y=0$ (since $e_{ii}$ acts as the identity on $e_{ii}Y$ and as $0$ on all other $e_{jj}Y$s). Moreover, observe $e_{ii}Y\cong e_{jj}Y$ as $R$-modules, with multiplications by $e_{ij}$ and $e_{ji}$ as mutually inverse homomorphisms (hence isomorphisms), from which we conclude $Y\cong X^n$ as $M_n(R)$-modules with $X=e_{ii}Y$.

So the inverse of $X\mapsto X^n$ is $Y\mapsto e_{11}Y$.

Comment: I think there's a problem in your proof of $e_{ii}Y \simeq e_{jj}Y$, since multiplying $e_{ii}$ by the permutation matrix associated to the transpositions $(ij)$ can only give you $e_{ji}$, not $e_{jj}$.

Comment: @penseur_32 True. Fixed.